# Error al crear un projecto angular?

Tags: angular6

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
ya tengo instaldo el angular cli global. pero ala hora de crear un prjecto nuevo me sale este error

Comment: Martín bienvenido, te recomiendo que no subas capturas de pantalla al momento de preguntar, es mejor que pongas en bloque de código el error. Es mas comprensible para todos y mas ligero al momento de cargar la página. Yendo al tema, instalaste ya node y npm?

Comment: gracias hermano porla recomendacion. y si ya tengo intalado el node  y  npm.